# I want to understand the concept of list comprehension in python

Tags: python, list-comprehension

### Given code

```
x=[(a,b) for a in range(3) for b in range(a)]
print(x)
```

### Output

```
[(1, 0), (2, 0), (2, 1)]
```

I know the comprehension can be broken down as follows:

```
for a in range(3):
    for b in range(a):
        print(a,b)
```

Can someone explain me how the output came as such provided above....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is this:

1. first, `a=0` so the inner loop skips as `range(0)` returns an empty list.
2. then, `a=1` so the inner loop is only executed for `0` as range(1) is qual to `[0]` so the first pair is `(1, 0)`
3. `a=2` and the inner loop runs for `b=0` and `b=1` hence the other two pair `(2, 0)` and `(2, 1)`

I think it's clear what's going on now. right?

Answer (score 2):

The list comprehension is not translated to:

```
for a in range(3):
    for b in range(a):
        print(a,b)
```

but rather to:

```
x = []
for a in range(3):
    for b in range(a):
        x.append((a, b))
```

Answer (score 1):

You are running in parallel `range(3)` and `range(a)`.

What effectively happens is that `a` is being set to `0`, `1` and finally `2`.

Then, your `b` is defined for each element in `range(a)`.

Now data is generated:

```
a = 0
range(0) # nothing
a = 1
range(1) # (0, )
(1, 0) # first pair of (a, b) for a = 1
a = 2
range(2) # (0, 1)
(2, 0) # first pair of (a, b) for a = 2
(2, 1) # second pair of (a, b) for a = 2
# end
```

Given the above, result ends up being `[(1, 0), (2, 0), (2, 1)]`

Answer (score 0):

what the list comprehension does is this:

```
ret = []
for a in range(3):
    for b in range(a):
        ret.append((a,b))

print(ret)  # [(1, 0), (2, 0), (2, 1)]
```

which returns the list you are getting...